# How can I integrate with gnosis safe multisig in dapp?

Tags: dapps

I plan to use gnosis safe multisig for our smart contract. Any sdk or something I can work with? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the zodiac module, a set of standard tools for DAO's using the Gnosis-Safe :  https://github.com/gnosis/zodiac